# How do I use the RangeAttribute in a method call?

Tags: c#, console-application

Experimenting with the RangeAttribute in a console application by attempting the following:

```
public void Roll([Range(0,10)] int pins)
```

Would be great if an exception were thrown if the value passed was outside of a range. However, though it complies, it allows any value through. What needs to be done to make use of this attribute?

Comment: Attributes are meta-programming:  The runtime doesn't do anything special with them. You have to write (reflection) code that looks for the attribute(s) you care about, and then do something with them.

Comment: A similar question was asked here: [Validating DataAnnotations on method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343137/validating-dataannotations-on-method-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'hidden' compiler magic that would interpret that attribute and apply any sort of validation for that argument. However, you can use reflection, find that attribute yourself and perform the validation.